# Developing own firefox add-on along with other add-on's

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I would like develop on add-on for Firefox , which combine with other available add-on's and make new add-on which providing new features + existing add on feature tooo.

Comment: I guess you need to be more specific with what you are trying to achieve. The question as is is not answerable.

Comment: Whether now its understandable . if not please let me know ..

Comment: So you would like to group several add-ons together so that they can be installed with a single XPI installer?

Comment: Yes and i would like to change some of feature existing add-on too

Comment: Just remember to follow licenses that apply to any code you "rip" apart for your new extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear, but here is some information from Mozilla.

[How to develop a Firefox extension](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)

and

[Developing Mozilla addons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Developing_add-ons)

Comment: i agree with this .. But i am planning to develop the a new add-on , along with already existing add-on providing new features for my own purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You will find the code of all installed extensions in the firefox profile folder. In my vista machine, it is located at `C:\Users\<ur name>\appdata\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<randomstring>.default\extensions\`

Unzip the jars and learn the code, edit as per your needs and restart firefox. Remember that when firefox automatically updates the extension, ur changes will be overriden. If something goes wrong, start firefox from cmd with -P switch to create a new profile or goto safe mode using `firefox -safe-mode` and uninstall and reinstall the extension from its website.